# How do I perform a JS computation within a const in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a React component that outputs content from an API endpoint.

I am successfully able to display the content, but now I want to add some computation to what is being displayed.

In this example, I want the `Badge` to be green success badge if the current object has a status of "Enabled", and I want the `Badge` to be a yellow warning badge if the current object has a status of "Paused".

It does not appear that I can simply use JavaScript here. Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
    const renderInformation = data.map((item) => (
    <Card
      key={item.id}
      title={item.name}
      actions={[{ content: "Details" }]}
    >
      <Card.Section>
        <Stack>
          if (item.status == 'enabled') { // <---- THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO USE AN IF STATEMENT
            <Badge status="success">Enabled</Badge>
          }
          if (item.status == 'paused') { // <---- THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO USE AN IF STATEMENT
            <Badge status="attention">Paused</Badge>
          }
        </Stack>
      </Card.Section>
    </Card>
  ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use js with jsx, just add a {} around your js code. And better use expression than statement.
so you code will look like below:

```
const renderInformation = data.map((item) => (
  <Card
    key={item.id}
    title={item.name}
    actions={[{ content: "Details" }]}
  >
    <Card.Section>
      <Stack>
        {item.status == 'enabled'&& <Badge status="success">Enabled</Badge>}
        {item.status == 'paused' && <Badge status="attention">Paused</Badge>}
      </Stack>
    </Card.Section>
  </Card>
));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   const renderInformation = data.map((item) => (
    <Card
      key={item.id}
      title={item.name}
      actions={[{ content: "Details" }]}
    >
      <Card.Section>
        <Stack>
          {item.status == 'enabled' && <Badge status="success">Enabled</Badge> }
          {item.status == 'paused' && <Badge status="attention">Paused</Badge> }
        </Stack>
      </Card.Section>
    </Card>
  ));
```